# requesting and using multiple ips on same node

Tags: delphi, networking

The goal is to make a virtual LAN network on single host. How can I get multiple IPs and also stick them to TCP Clients resident on a single host?

Any help will be appreciated. I would like to use indy for the purpose, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You first configure your OS, and then you run your servers/clientes binding them to any address available to the program

Comment: It is, as i don't want the user to do it nor through any OS settings. It will be done as the app is run automatically and the amount of IPs, clients will change in real-time with full control on who gets which IP. Most likely it will use Windows-API based routines.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a set of virtual IPs to a network interface. Have your clients choose an IP from the set and bind() to that IP.

Comment: How can i do it in code? Also will other people in the LAN be able to communicate with those clients through those IPs?

Comment: Assigning the virtual IPs to the interface is an OS specific thing. You can set up a script to do it at boot time. Mr. Google would know more. You can point DNS records to these virtual IPs and have your services look up the IP by name and bind the listening service to the appropriate IP. If you assign the virtual IPs from the LAN's address range, they can be used on any properly configured machine on the LAN.